# Insert query with an inner join

Tags: mysql

I want to make my insert query which has an inner join to a user's data table.

The example of the tables is like this:

`users:`

```
uid | name
```

---

`users_data:`

```
id | data_id | uid | other fields
```

---

`data_stocks`

```
id | data_id | quantity
```

---

So im trying to insert into `data_stocks` relating to only knowing the `uid` from `users`.

Kinda of like this:

```
INSERT INTO data_stocks (data_id,quantity)
VALUES (' need to join it some how ','$quantity');
```

Is this possible in mySQL?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want to use the `insert ... select` form of the statement:

```
INSERT INTO data_stocks (data_id,quantity)
    select ud.data_id, $quantity
    from users u join
         users_data ud
         on u.uid = ud.uid;
```

If you are doing this for only one user, it might look more like this:

```
INSERT INTO data_stocks (data_id,quantity)
    select ud.data_id, $quantity
    from users_data ud
    where ud.uid = $uid;
```