# I want to join two tables in my database

Tags: mysql, database, join

I search in internet but i want some more sufficient answer. when i join a full of rows table in my database with an empty table from the same database. All the rows, from the full of rows table, will create also in the empty table?? That is the purpose of a join two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to display either one of the table even if the other table is empty, then use `left or right join`.

**INNER JOIN**

This is the simplest, most understood Join and is the most common. This query will return all of the records in the left table (table A) that have a matching record in the right table (table B)

**LEFT JOIN**

This query will return all of the records in the left table (table A) regardless if any of those records have a match in the right table (table B). It will also return any matching records from the right table.

**RIGHT JOIN**

This query will return all of the records in the right table (table B) regardless if any of those records have a match in the left table (table A). It will also return any matching records from the left table

[Here's the complete guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: if i do a join in my code and i go in phpmyadmin to see the empty table it will have values?

Comment: the answer is no, because it's just for query,.  `JOIN`” is an SQL keyword used to query data from two or more related tables..  if you want to store to database, you need `insert`

Comment: visit this. to understand more about join, http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: you can use join to query data, and save that to database using insert. . visit this link, for inserting data that came from a query, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666443/insert-query-with-an-inner-join